# How I can install Bluetooth driver on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I was installing Bluetooth on my ASUS desktop computer with AMD A8-65000Apu with Radeon(tm) processor.I have downloaded the driver package from Intel download-center but it's not working. I have checked in my device manager, it doesn't show any Bluetooth device or hardware.

To be more clear, I don't have any Bluetooth but now I want to install Bluetooth driver so that I can connect my Bluetooth headphones to the system.

I want to know how I can do it. Please help.

Comment: "It's not working" care to be more specific? Do you have an Intel Bluetooth device because you have an AMD platform so that would be extremely odd.  In other words the driver you installed doesn't go to your Bluetooth device

Comment: okay let me be more clear, I don't have any Bluetooth but now I want to install Bluetooth driver so that I can connect my Bluetooth headphones to the system.

Comment: Can you see the Bluetooth headphones in Windows settings app? I did not install any driver. It works for me automatically.

Comment: Windows settings app - where in this?

Comment: If you don't have a Bluetooth receiver/device  then you cannot connect your headphones to your computer.  What you want isn't possible go out and purchase a USB Bluetooth receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not install the driver, if the hardware is not connected first.

If you dont have a blutooth hardware (bluetooth module as a part of the computer specification) you can not install the driver and the bluetooth to apear. Second, how come you are downloading drivers for "AMD" from "Intel", those are 2 different companies? You first need a bluetooth hardware inside your computer, than to install the driver. If the bluetooth does not show in "Device manager" you might not have a bluetooth hardware on this computer (tell us the brand of the computer, not the processor so we can check for bluetooth hardware).

If its a desktop computer, it probably does not have a bluetooth hardware inside, you need an external one, than to install the drivers, than to connect the bluetooth headphones.

Comment: what does hardware mean? you mean if headphones are not connected? or some other hardware and I have only Windows 10, I have no option other than windows 10

Comment: If you dont have a blutooth hardware (bluetooth module as a part of the computer specification) you can not install the driver and the bluetooth to apear. Second, how come you are downloading drivers for "AMD" from "Intel", those are 2 different companies? You first need a bluetooth hardware inside your computer, than to install the driver. If the bluetooth does not show in "Device manager" you might not have a bluetooth hardware on this computer (tell us the brand of the computer, not the processor so we can check for bluetooth hardware).

Comment: the brand of computer is  ASUS

Comment: Since this is a desktop computer, you probably need an external bluetooth module first, than to install the driver for the external module, than to connect the headphones.

Comment: We need the model number "Asus X55VD", "Asus X55C", etc. Is this a desktop or laptop computer? If its a laptop than there should be a sticker near the keyboard where the model is written or it should be on the back of the laptop, maybe something like "X55V series".

Comment: okay!! Got It. 
It's A desktop.

Comment: Your desktop doesn't have a Bluetooth receiver so you will be unable to connect your Bluetooth headset to it

Comment: My comment was directed at the author of the question.

Comment: And I have another Question my headphones have a single end wire also so that I can plug in the Desktop. But I don't know where is single jack which can take both mic and speaker at same time

Comment: You need 2 ports.  One for the microphone and one for the speaker.  A single combination port doesn't exist unless your saying it's a USB connector